# Rotate an item on a background image with transform and js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a background image and another image element as needle. So you will see 3 tabs above the snippet page. My goal is to change the position of the needle when you click to the buttons. But there are some problems like if you click 2nd or 3th tab first, the needle moves wrong direction.

And if you move between 3th and 1st tabs the bottom of needle is moving out of the black little circle.

How can I achieve my purpose without any visual errors? Maybe some other way to achieve this?

```js
function asama3() {
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.transform = "rotate(-68deg)";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.left = "210px";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.top = "178px";
}
function asama2() {
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.transform = "rotate(-107deg)";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.left = "157px";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.top = "180px";
}
function asama1() {
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.transform = "rotate(-145deg)";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.left = "113px";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.top = "211px";
}
```

```css
#ibre {
    width:150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 258px;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer; float:left; background-color:red; color:#fff; width:200px;"><h1 onclick="asama1()">1. aşama</h1></div>
        <div style="cursor: pointer; float:left; background-color:red; color:#fff; width:200px;"><h1 onclick="asama2()">2. aşama</h1></div>
        <div style="cursor: pointer; float:left; background-color:red; color:#fff; width:200px;"><h1 onclick="asama3()">3. aşama</h1></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        
    <div style=" background-image: url('https://i.hizliresim.com/WNguZF.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:281px; width:500px;">
    <div style=""><img id="ibre" style=""  src="https://i.hizliresim.com/Hmuavw.png"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it rotates at the center, you can create a hidden `div` and wrap them both in an outer `div` and makes sure the center lines up with the black dot:

```js
function asama3() {
  document.getElementById("outer").style.transform = "rotate(68deg)";
}

function asama2() {
  document.getElementById("outer").style.transform = "rotate(107deg)";
}

function asama1() {
  document.getElementById("outer").style.transform = "rotate(145deg)";
}
```

```css
#outer {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 108px;
  top: 278px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#ibre {
  width: 150px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #070707;
}

#hidden {
  width: 150px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer; float:left; background-color:red; color:#fff; width:200px;">
  <h1 onclick="asama1()">1. aşama</h1>
</div>
<div style="cursor: pointer; float:left; background-color:red; color:#fff; width:200px;">
  <h1 onclick="asama2()">2. aşama</h1>
</div>
<div style="cursor: pointer; float:left; background-color:red; color:#fff; width:200px;">
  <h1 onclick="asama3()">3. aşama</h1>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div style=" background-image: url('https://i.hizliresim.com/WNguZF.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:281px; width:500px;">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="ibre"></div>

    <div id="hidden"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way it pivots on that dot to wherever you need it pointing.

Comment: Excellent. I will edit it for my needs, perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, i think

```js
function asama3() {
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.transform = "rotate(140deg)";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.left = "250px";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.top = "220px";
}
function asama2() {
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.transform = "rotate(80deg)";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.left = "165px";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.top = "190px";
}
function asama1() {
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.transform = "rotate(40deg)";
    document.getElementById("ibre").style.top = "220px";
  document.getElementById("ibre").style.left = "120px";

}
```

```css
#ibre {
    width:150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 270px;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer; float:left; background-color:red; color:#fff; width:200px;"><h1 onclick="asama1()">1. aşama</h1></div>
        <div style="cursor: pointer; float:left; background-color:red; color:#fff; width:200px;"><h1 onclick="asama2()">2. aşama</h1></div>
        <div style="cursor: pointer; float:left; background-color:red; color:#fff; width:200px;"><h1 onclick="asama3()">3. aşama</h1></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        
    <div style=" background-image: url('https://i.hizliresim.com/WNguZF.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:281px; width:500px;">
    <div style=""><img id="ibre" style=""  src="https://i.hizliresim.com/Hmuavw.png"></div>
    </div>
```